# Docker: How to control/define default gateway settings

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

Can anyone shed some light on what is what with the Docker Compose YML file?
All I want to do is to be able to control the IP addresses of the various containers.  I am using version 3.1 (but also tried 3.3 as I recently upgraded to version 17.06).  The documentation says:

```
A full example:

ipam:
  driver: default
  config:
    - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
Note: Additional IPAM configurations, such as gateway, are only honored for version 2 at the moment.
```

When I do this, I need that subnet honored when I inspect the network.  However the gateway is completely different [**read the Note: above]**, so the containers do not start.  Why did they lose capability (*at the moment*) in version 3 for something that worked in version 2?  Worse, why wasn't that restored in version 3.2 or 3.3?

Maybe I am way off base here - certainly wouldn't be first time!  What is most important to me: is there a way to modify a compose file to allow a `docker stack deploy` command (in a `Docker Swarm`) to provide control of the gateway and subnets used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured this out and I am posting what I did in the hopes that it might help someone else.  While I did not know this when I started, what I really wanted [needed? :) ] to do was to redefine the default settings of the `docker_gwbridge` network.

This is how I did that:

```
docker swarm init     # I am assuming this was already done, this creates the network with default settings
docker swarm leave -f  # only if you did an 'init'
docker network ls      # just to see the docker_gwbridge network
docker network rm docker_gwbridge

# if you never created/initialized a swarm, you can start here
SUBNET=172.19.0.0/16   # my defaults were always 172.18, using 19 only to test that this works
GATEWAY=172.19.0.1
docker network create --subnet=$SUBNET --gateway $GATEWAY \
  -o com.docker.network.bridge.name=docker_gwbridge \
  -o com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc=false \
  -o com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade=true \ 
  docker_gwbridge
docker swarm init      # now start the swarm
docker network inspect docker_gwbridge   # if you want to see your changes
docker stack deploy --compose-file yourFile.yml YOURSTACKNAME
```

Now all your containers start on the subnet you defined as well as using the gateway you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration of a network within compose v3 is:

```
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      -
        subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

You can then assign your containers to this network and specify the IP

```
services
    my_service:
        networks:
            my_network:
                 ipv4_address: 172.28.0.100
```

For already defined networks, use:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-pre-existing-network
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to imply that is 'honored', but the containers fail to start because the gateway, which you also don't show, gets set to the default, say 172.18.1.1

Comment: You can always create the network yourself, `docker network create --gateway "whatever"` and attach your containers to it

Comment: tried that and then docker stack deploy fails because that network already exists.   Ick....